# nginx lua get response body

Tags: nginx, lua

I need to get response body eg. the response html code from url i am using following code.

```
location /configure/result.php {

  log_by_lua_block  {
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "REQUEST capturing started")

    json = require "json"

    function getval(v, def)
      if v == nil then
         return def
      end
      return v
    end

    local data = {
      request={},
      response={}
    }
    local req = data.request
    local resp = data.response

    req["host"] = ngx.var.host
    req["uri"] = ngx.var.uri
    req["headers"] = ngx.req.get_headers()
    req["time"] = ngx.req.start_time()
    req["method"] = ngx.req.get_method()
    req["get_args"] = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
    req["post_args"] = ngx.req.get_post_args()
    req["body"] = ngx.var.request_body

    content_type = getval(ngx.var.CONTENT_TYPE, "")

    resp["headers"] = ngx.resp.get_headers()
    resp["status"] = ngx.status
    resp["duration"] = ngx.var.upstream_response_time
    resp["time"] = ngx.now()
    resp["body"] = ngx.var.response_body -- Problem Here

    ngx.log(ngx.CRIT, json.encode(data));
  }
}
```

But it does not log the response data it recieved from that url eg. the processed source code how could i get the response.data?

My idea is to get response data then use regEx to read specifiq value from the source code which will then do x-y

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this now, but maybe response is unaccessible during the log phase of request processing?

You can try to get response data within the `body_filter_by_lua_block` using ['ngx.ctx'](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxctx) table:

```
    body_filter_by_lua_block {
        ngx.ctx.response_body = ngx.arg[1]
    }
```

and then use it within the `log_by_lua_block` block:

```
    log_by_lua_block {
        ...
        resp["body"] = ngx.ctx.response_body
        ngx.log(ngx.CRIT, json.encode(data))
    }
```

(please note this is just a guess, please let me know if this works)